# Divide number by factors

Tags: beginner, f#, factors

I'm learning F#.
The code below gets a number e.g. 100 and list of factors and should divide that number by the factors without any rest. (There is an actual code I've got in C#, but this is F# port).

I especially didn't liked equalsDifference function.. any better solution?

```
namespace RozbijaczApp
module Rozbijacz =
    let precision = 2

    let minUnit = 1m / (pown 10m precision)

    let round x = System.Math.Round(decimal x, precision, System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

    let mainMapper factor factorSum x = 
        round (x * factor / factorSum)

    let equalsDifference minUnit (difference: decimal) (l: decimal list) =
        let listSize = List.length l
        let mutable acc = difference

        [for i in [0..listSize-1] do
            let element = l |> List.item i
            if acc <> 0m then
                if difference < 0m then
                    if element >= minUnit then
                        acc <- acc + minUnit
                        yield element - minUnit
                    else
                        yield element
                else
                    acc <- acc - minUnit
                    yield element + minUnit
            else    
                yield element
        ]

    let divider (number:decimal) factors = 
        let factorsSum = factors |> List.sum 
        let result = factors |> List.map (fun x -> mainMapper number factorsSum x)
        let controlSum = result |> List.sum 
        let difference = number - controlSum
        printfn "Difference %O" difference
        // add or substract diffenernce by minUnit for results
        let fixResult = equalsDifference minUnit difference result
        let finalControlSum = fixResult |> List.sum 
        let finalDifference = number - finalControlSum
        printfn "Final difference %O should by zero"finalDifference

        fixResult
```

and usage:

```
        let factors = [0.2m;0.3m;0.4m]
        let results = Rozbijacz.divider 100m factors
        printfn "Result: %A" results
```

ok, as you suggested map is better:

```
let equalsDifference minUnit (difference: decimal) (l: decimal list) =
    let listSize = List.length l
    let mutable acc = difference

    let resp = l |> List.map (fun element -> (
        if acc <> 0m then
            if difference < 0m then
                if element >= minUnit then
                    acc <- acc + minUnit
                    element - minUnit
                else
                    element
            else
                acc <- acc - minUnit
                element + minUnit
        else    
            element
        ) )
    resp
```

But is this enough? Any F# magic?

Comment: Regarding `equalsDifference`, why don't you use `List.map` over `l`?

Comment: The for loop should be `List.map`

Comment: @JohnPalmer Please write all critiques, even trivial ones, in an answer. Comments are for seeking to clarify the question, and may be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using mutable variables, it is possible to apply the fold:

```
let equalsDifference minUnit difference l =
    l
    |> List.fold
        (fun (acc,xs) element -> 
               if acc <> 0m then
                  if difference < 0m then
                     if element >= minUnit then
                         acc + minUnit, (element - minUnit)::xs
                     else
                         acc, element::xs
                  else
                     acc - minUnit, (element + minUnit)::xs
               else
                  acc, element::xs)
        (difference, [])
    |> snd
    |> List.rev
```